# Generic Vector class inheriting from non generic LineSegmentClass

Tags: c#, generics, vector

I am attempting to write a Vector class that can represent Forces and Dimensions. Normally this is not a problem because most people make a property called Magnitude that returns a double. Double's don't care what they represent they represent forces or dimensions just fine. However, I am using [this open-source library called Unit Class Library](https://github.com/ParagonTruss/UnitClassLibrary) to represent Dimensions and Forces.

Here is the sort of thing I would like to do. Is there any way to have a property return a different Type depending on `T` (Same thing would happen in the constructor). Is it possible, and if so how?

```
public class Vector<T> : LineSegment
{
    ForceUnit _magnitudeForce;

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the magnitude of the vector (equals the length of the line segment parent if T is Dimension, if T is Force, return variable )
    /// </summary>
    public T Magnitude
    {
        get {

            Type typeT = typeof(T);

            if (typeT == typeof(Dimension))
            {
                return base.Length;
            }
            else if (typeT == typeof(ForceUnit))
            {
                return _magnitudeForce;
            }

        ...
    }
```

Or is there something tricky I can do with the `dynamic` keyword to achieve this?

Or should I make an set of interfaces like this to go on top of the [Unit Library](https://github.com/ParagonTruss/UnitClassLibrary):

```
interface IDistance
{
    double Centimeters { get; }
    double Feet { get; }
    double Inches { get; }
    double Kilometers { get; }
    double Meters { get; }
    double Miles { get; }
    double Millimeters { get; }
    double Sixteenths { get; }
    double ThirtySeconds { get; }
    double Yards { get; }
}

interface IForceUnit
{
    double Kips { get; }
    double Newtons { get; }
    double Pounds { get; }
}
```

And then make a Hybrid class that implements both to be used as the Magnitude for the Class.

I run the [Unit Class Library](https://github.com/ParagonTruss/UnitClassLibrary) so any changes that should be made there are welcome to be suggested. But please keep in mind that the intuitiveness and unit conversion ability of the library is a value of the project I want to keep.

Comment: You can certainly do that, but does that needs to be generic? IMO if you checking `typeof(T)` with bunch of if statements or a switch statement, your method/class/property shouldn't be generic at all.

Comment: I agree its not optimal, nor is it usually necessary. Magnitude is however, the only property that will differ between all of the different Vector Classes I could make. Is it really worth adding all of the code from line segment into each different non-dimension Vector class ?

Comment: By dimension you mean length? As in MASS, LENGTH, TIME unit dimensions.

Comment: Look at the project linked in the question

Comment: Any unit system where the units are statically defined is bound to fail. What happens when you need to represent angle per second for example? You can't hard code all possible combinations of units. The system needs to derive the units from the base units.

Comment: This would have been trivial if all the units derived from `IUnit` and had some common properties (like their value). I suggest to ditch this unit library and find a better one.

Comment: Not sure i understand what you mean by using an interface for the unit. Could you expand on that a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just derive from Vector and throw away the parent Magnitude value that is a Dimension?

With something like this?

```
public class Load:Vector
{

    private ForceUnit _magnitude;

    public ForceUnit Magnitude
    {
        get
        {
                return this._magnitude;          
        }
    }



    public PointLoad(ForceUnit magnitudeOfLoad, Vector directionVector)
        : base(...)
    {
        _magnitude = magnitudeOfLoad;
    }

}
```

Comment: Any drawbacks to this simple approach that im not seeing?

Comment: The major drawback I see is that you have to stick to predefined units. No derived units allowed in this scheme.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely don't want to do that type checking - what you're better off doing is creating an abstract base class or an interface and then deriving from it.

For example if you use an abstract class:

```
public abstract class Vector<T> : LineSegment
{
    public abstract T Magnitude { get; }
}

public class DimensionVector : Vector<Dimension>
{
    public override Dimension Magnitude { get { return base.Length; } }
}

public class ForceUnitVector : Vector<ForceUnit>
{
    ForceUnit magnitudeForce;

    public override ForceVector Magnitude { get { return this.magnitudeForce; } }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me offer and alternative unit library. This will allow you to not have to deal with generics and can work with derived units. Here is the example first:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Vector A=new Vector(Unit.Foot, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 1.0);
        Vector B=A.ConvertTo(Unit.Inch);
        Vector C=B*B; // Convert to square inches, compatible with SI units of m^2

        Debug.WriteLine(A.ToString());  // [0.3,0.5,0.7,1]
        Debug.WriteLine(B.ToString());  // [3.6,6,8.4,12]
        Debug.WriteLine(C.ToString());  // [12.96,36,70.56,144]

        Vector F=new Vector(Unit.PoundForce, 100.0, 130.0, 150.0, 180.0);

        Vector K=F/B;   // Stiffness is force per distance, compatible with SI units of kg/m^2
        Vector P=F/C;   // Pressure is force per area, compatible with SI units kg/(m*s^2)

        Debug.WriteLine(F.ToString());  // [100,130,150,180]
        Debug.WriteLine(K.ToString());  // [27.78,21.67,17.86,15]
        Debug.WriteLine(P.ToString());  // [7.716,3.611,2.126,1.25]

        var x=3*Unit.Foot.FactorTo(Unit.Inch);  // x=36 inches

    }
}
```

The `Unit` class is:

```
public class Unit : IEquatable<Unit>
{
    readonly int M, L, T; // base unit powers. For example Area: (M=0, L=2, T=0)
    readonly double x; // base unit factor. For example 1 km = (1000)*m

    public Unit(int M, int L, int T, double factor)
    {
        this.M=M;
        this.L=L;
        this.T=T;
        this.x=factor;
    }
    public Unit(Unit other)
    {
        this.M=other.M;
        this.L=other.L;
        this.T=other.T;
        this.x=other.x;
    }
    public int[] Dimension { get { return new int[] { M, L, T }; } }
    public double Factor { get { return x; } }
    public bool IsConvertibleTo(Unit other) { return M==other.M&&L==other.L&&T==other.T; }
    public double FactorTo(Unit target)
    {
        if(IsConvertibleTo(target))
        {
            return Factor/target.Factor;
        }
        throw new ArgumentException("Incompatible units in target.");
    }
    #region IEquatable Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Equality overrides from <see cref="System.Object"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">The object to compare this with</param>
    /// <returns>False if object is a different type, otherwise it calls <code>Equals(Unit)</code></returns>
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if(obj is Unit)
        {
            return Equals((Unit)obj);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks for equality among <see cref="Unit"/> classes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="other">The other <see cref="Unit"/> to compare it to</param>
    /// <returns>True if equal</returns>
    public bool Equals(Unit other)
    {
        return M==other.M
            &&L==other.L
            &&T==other.T
            &&x.Equals(other.x);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates the hash code for the <see cref="Unit"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The int hash value</returns>
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (((17*23+M.GetHashCode())*23+L.GetHashCode())*23+T.GetHashCode())*23+x.GetHashCode();
    }

    #endregion
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}(M:{1},L:{2},T:{3})", Factor, M, L, T);
    }
    public static Unit operator*(double relative, Unit unit)
    {
        return new Unit(unit.M, unit.L, unit.T, relative*unit.Factor);
    }
    public static Unit operator/(Unit unit, double divisor)
    {
        return new Unit(unit.M, unit.L, unit.T, unit.Factor/divisor);
    }

    public static Unit operator*(Unit unit, Unit other)
    {
        return new Unit(
            unit.M+other.M,
            unit.L+other.L,
            unit.T+other.T,
            unit.Factor*other.Factor);
    }
    public static Unit operator/(Unit unit, Unit other)
    {
        return new Unit(
            unit.M-other.M,
            unit.L-other.L,
            unit.T-other.T,
            unit.Factor/other.Factor);
    }

    public static Unit operator^(Unit unit, int power)
    {
        return new Unit(
            unit.M*power,
            unit.L*power,
            unit.T*power,
            Math.Pow(unit.Factor, power));
    }

    public static readonly Unit Meter=new Unit(0, 1, 0, 1.0);
    public static readonly Unit Millimeter=0.001*Meter;
    public static readonly Unit Inch=25.4*Millimeter;
    public static readonly Unit Foot=12*Inch;
    public static readonly Unit Yard=3*Foot;

    public static readonly Unit Second=new Unit(0, 0, 1, 1.0);
    public static readonly Unit Minute=60*Second;
    public static readonly Unit Hour=60*Minute;

    public static readonly Unit Kilogram=new Unit(1, 0, 0, 1.0);
    public static readonly Unit PoundMass=0.453592*Kilogram;
    public static readonly Unit Newton=Kilogram*(Meter/(Second^2));
    public static readonly Unit PoundForce=4.44822162*Newton;
}
```

to be used in the `Vector` class

```
public class Vector 
{

    public Vector(Unit unit, int size)
    {
        this.Elements=new double[size];
        this.Unit=unit;
    }
    public Vector(Unit unit, params double[] values)
    {
        this.Unit=unit;
        this.Elements=values;
    }

    public Unit Unit { get; private set; }
    public double[] Elements { get; private set; }

    public double this[int index] { get { return Elements[index]; } }
    public int Count { get { return Elements.Length; } }

    public Vector ConvertTo(Unit target)
    {
        double factor=Unit.FactorTo(target);
        double[] values=Array.ConvertAll(Elements, (x) => factor*x);
        return new Vector(target, values);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string[] items=Array.ConvertAll(Elements, (x) => x.ToString());

        return string.Format("[{0}] in {1}", string.Join(",", items), Unit.ToString());
    }

    public static Vector operator+(Vector x, Vector y)
    {
        if(x.Count==y.Count)
        {
            x=x.ConvertTo(y.Unit);

            double[] result=new double[x.Count];
            for(int i=0; i<result.Length; i++)
            {
                result[i]=x[i]+y[i];
            }
            return new Vector(y.Unit, result);
        }
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Vectors must have the same number of elements.");
    }
    public static Vector operator-(Vector x, Vector y)
    {
        if(x.Count==y.Count)
        {
            x=x.ConvertTo(y.Unit);

            double[] result=new double[x.Count];
            for(int i=0; i<result.Length; i++)
            {
                result[i]=x[i]-y[i];
            }
            return new Vector(y.Unit, result);
        }
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Vectors must have the same number of elements.");
    }
    public static Vector operator*(double x, Vector y)
    {
        double[] result=new double[y.Count];
        for(int i=0; i<result.Length; i++)
        {
            result[i]=x*y[i];
        }
        return new Vector(y.Unit, result);
    }
    public static Vector operator*(Vector x, Vector y)
    {
        if(x.Count==y.Count)
        {
            double[] result=new double[x.Count];
            for(int i=0; i<result.Length; i++)
            {
                result[i]=x[i]*y[i];
            }
            return new Vector(x.Unit* y.Unit, result);
        }
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Vectors must have the same number of elements.");
    }
    public static Vector operator/(Vector x, Vector y)
    {
        if(x.Count==y.Count)
        {
            double[] result=new double[x.Count];
            for(int i=0; i<result.Length; i++)
            {
                result[i]=x[i]/y[i];
            }
            return new Vector(x.Unit/y.Unit, result);
        }
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Vectors must have the same number of elements.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course the `Unit` class would need to be expanded to include more built in units. Angle measurements don't have units so there should also be `static readonly Unit Radian = new Unit(0,0,0,1.0);` and `Degree = 180/Math.PI*Radian`

Comment: Also the unit exponents (`M,L,T` values) should be rational numbers so a whole other `Fraction` class needs to be developed and used instead of `int` to properly handle units with rational exponents like `L=3/2`.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. I think you are spot on in pointing out the limitations of the Unit Classes. I am working through the idea of the angle property and fraction class now.

Comment: I have some other questions I would like to ask about this implementation that will probably be to extensive for comments, would you join me in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59111/generic-unit-class)?

Comment: Can you give me more insight into your `FactorTo`and `IsConvertableTo` Methods ? It seems IsConvertable should be renamed `IsSameUnitsAs. And `FactorTo` seems to be just division

Comment: Yes, I meant to include them in the example. `IsConvertibleTo()` would check if two units are compatible for conversion. Same unit implies `inches=inches` by compatible means `inches <--> feet`.

Comment: `FactorTo()` gives you the conversion factor between two compatible units. Remember the `Unit` class does not hold quantities, only their units. To convert quantities like `3 feet into inches` you would do `3*Feet.FactorTo(Inches)`.

Comment: Make sure you implement `IEquatable<Unit>` where you check if `(M,L,T)` exponents match, and also the scaling `x` matches.

Comment: After viewing Jeremy Lin's answer. It seems that his answer is a lot simpler and sticks closer to the SOLID principle of having each class having one responsibility. Are there any drawbacks to his answer?

Comment: `Unit` class has ONE responsibility. To represent the dimensionality of quantities (also known as units). This is for both base units and derived units. The other solutions are limited in that a) Units can only be used with Vector quantities and not other data types and b) the units handles are statically defined and there is no relationship between them. I can automatically convert between `square feet` and `square millimeters` without having to pre-code all possible combinations of units.

Answer (score 1):

You can return an object or dynamic, and cast it.

However, I advise you not to do this, even because not make sense.
I advise you to review your logic.

```
public object Magnitude
    {
        get {

            Type typeT = typeof(T);

            if (typeT == typeof(Dimension))
            {
                return base.Length;
            }
            else if (typeT == typeof(ForceUnit))
            {
                return _magnitudeForce;
            }

        ...
    }
```